# I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to activate "module load python2 samtools rseqc" but I'm running into Lmod version issues

Tags: linux, unix, bioinformatics, mobaxterm, samtools

I keep receiving this error;

```
ERROR: rseqc/3.0.0 requires several additional modules. Run the following
commands to load all of the dependencies (including this module):
```

But when I try to load in python3 I get this error;

```
Lmod has detected the following error:  Cannot load module "python3/3.7.9" because these module(s) are loaded:
   anaconda3
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
module purge
module load python2 samtools rseqc
```

This unloads all loaded modules to prevent dependency conflicts when loading your desired modules.